# PHP: Using img src in table based on time duration

Tags: php

I had some help on the 'img src' of my table below to show the up and down image based on a positive or negative number. This works great for what I need on that particular one.

I want to reuse this code to show up.png if avgduration is greater than 00:01:00,

or down.png if it's greater than 00:02:00.

And avgduration is varchar.

I have tried several different combinations and hours of research to figure it out but I can't find the right answer

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
    echo "<h4><table border='5' column width='500'><tr><th><center>Call Taker</center></th><th><center>Duration from Call Received to First Status</center></th><th><center> </center></th></></tr>";

$img = ["-1" => "../tms/images/down.png", 
"0" => "../tms/images/equal.png",
"1" => "..tms/images/up.png"];

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['CallTaker']. "</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['avgduration']."</center></td>";
   Echo '<td><center><img src="' . ($row['avgduration'] == 0 ? $img[$row['avgduration']] : $img[$row['avgduration']/abs($row['avgduration'])]) . '"></center></td>';;
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

This what the error I get currently:

> Notice: Undefined index: 00:05:11 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\calltaking.php on line 523

The code as it is, of course, does not work. It was used by me previously in another section and works as it for that particular table. I just don't know how to calculate it do what I need it to do.

Also, how do you add cellpadding to the cells? Doesn't matter what I put here, nothing changes. Not a necessaty but it would be nice
Signed,
Ready to my hair out

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the given code? Are you looking for a way to parse `$row['avgduration']` such that the comparison works?

Comment: Thanks for looking at @NicoHaase. The code in the block as it works fine to display the up.png if the avgduration is -5, etc. But now my return is going to look like 00:00:56, 00:02:03, etc and it it's 00:01:00 or below I would like it to display up.png. If it's 00:01:01 and up I would like it to display the down.png.

I know it doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: It doesn't have to make sense to others if it solves your problem ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your question, `$row['avgduration']` contains a string value like `00:01:01`. Comparing strings won't do the job here properly, but you can try to parse this to a pure integer value. A simple way could be:

```
function parseDate($input) {
    $parts = explode(':', $input);
    return $parts[2] + (60 * $parts[1]) + (3600 * $parts[0]);
}
```

Then you adjust your loop by using the parsed duration only:

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
{
    $parsedDuration = parseDuration($row['avgduration']);

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['CallTaker']. "</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['avgduration']."</center></td>";
    echo '<td><center><img src="' . ($parsedDuration == 0 ? $img[$parsedDuration] : $img[$parsedDuration/abs($parsedDuration)]) . '"></center></td>';
}
```

Comment: You are almost my saving grace. I got a little further than I have been. Here is what I get now:
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\calltaking.php on line 444---

And Line 444: echo '<td><center><img src="' . ($parsedDuration == 0 ? $img[$parsedDuration] : $img[$parsedDuration/abs($parsedDuration)]) . '"></center></td>';

Comment: Then just debug further: is `$img[1]` really set to the expected value? The given `$img` array uses string indices, not numeric ones